# React Native Firebase transaction not working properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an App using React Native and Firebase Real-Time Database.

In the database, I have some data as below.

```
myRoot
  |
  |--myValue1: 0
  |
  |--myValue2: 2
```

Then, I want to increase those values by one and get the following result.

```
myRoot
  |
  |--myValue1: 1
  |
  |--myValue2: 3
```

For this, I used a function as follows.

```
myFunction = () => {
   const myRef = firebase.database().ref('myRoot');

   return myRef.transaction((data) => {
      data.myValue1++;
      data.myValue2++;
      return data;
   })
   .then(console.log('Done'))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

But, after calling the function, I get the following error.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'data.myValue1')]
```

I tried taking a `snapshot` of `myRef` and print it in the console. It worked and printed the current values. But, `transaction` does not work and gives `null`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what caused the problem. The code segment is fine. The problem was in the dependencies. Just execute `npm install firebase --save` and then `npm install`. Restart the project. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check `data` for null, as this happens the first time the transaction handler function is called.  The handler will get called again with the snapshot, if it's present at the location of the database where you are performing the transaction.  You can see this check being performed in the sample code in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: It will look similar to the code in the documentation that l linked to.  You will have to decide what you want to do in the case that the snapshot is initially null and write that for yourself.

Comment: I tried. But, It only avoids the error. But, does not update the values.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I believe Sennen:

```
myFunction = () => {
   const myRef = firebase.database().ref('myRoot');

   myRef.transaction((data) => {
        if(data) {
            if(data.myValue1) {
                data.myValue1++;
            } 
            if(data.myValue2) {
                data.myValue2++;
            }
        }

        return data;
   })
   .then(console.log('Done'))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: I tried. But, It only avoids the error. But, does not update the values.